# How to convert a RGB image to black and white

Tags: python-3.x

So far, my code looks like this.

```
def paddedGray(img, b):

    img = [:,:,0], [:,:,1], [:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b

    return gray
```

As you can see, we were given parameters. So we don't have to specify the image.

I have imported

-numpy as np

-cv2

I dont think we are allowed to import PIL/pillow

On a sidenote, I am not trying to just get the answer and not learn how, so any tips/ explanation would really help.

(also, the parameter b is not related to this question im asking. I already have that part figured out.)

Thank you guys!

edit: formatting

Comment: What format is the `img` parameter in?

Comment: There are two images under the parameter "img"  They are .jpg and .png

Comment: You need to give us a lot more context than this. Give us an example of how this function would be called.

Comment: Is this all your own code? If not: do you see any relation between splitting the *image* in 3 channels and the *variables* conveniently named `r`, `g` and `b-but-not-your-b-argument`?